# bash script mkdir mv issue

Tags: bash, shell

i have the script below which is not working .. i could not manage to find the mistakes in it, can anyone help please.

```
 #!/bin/bash

Date=`date +%Y%m%d`
$HomeLogsPath=~/dir1/test/
$LogsBackupDir=~/dir1/backup/$Date/

service httpd stop

if [ -d "$HomeLogsPath" ]; then
cd $HomeLogsPath
pwd
mkdir -p "$LogsBackupDir"
mv * $LogsBackupDir
cd ~
pwd
fi

service httpd start
```

this is the error that i am getting

```
./restart.sh: line 4: =~/dir1/test/: No such file or directory
./restart.sh: line 5: =~/dir1/backup/20160506/: No such file or directory
```

thanks.

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: is the $HomeLogsPath directory exists move the files inside it to the backup directory $LogsBackupDir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` should only be used when substituting variables, not when assigning them.

```
foo=42
```

Answer (score 0):

## You mentioned $ sign in front of variable name during assignment, which is incorrect.

```
HomeLogsPath=~/dir1/test/
LogsBackupDir=~/dir1/backup/$Date/

test -d $HomeLogsPath
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ];then
mv $HomeLogsPath/* $LogsBackupDir

fi
```